# Maven xml bean - set classpath

Tags: java, xml, maven-3

I need to set the classpath for the maven xmlbean plugin since the xsd are depends upon my 2 java program which I don't wish to pack it as jar and added it to the dependencies.

Note : I dont wish to use maven ant plugin to do the above task.

Actual Error thrown by maven-xml plugin :

```
error: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements       'namespace@http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config  qname@http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config  extension@http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config'  instead of   'usertype@http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config'  here in element config @http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config
```

Since I have used 2 usertype in the xmlconfig and I am bit user maven-xmlplugin is unable to locates the classes. I even tried to package those classes and added in the dependencies though failed.

pom.xml

```
    <project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifacts</artifactId>
<version>V1</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>myartifacts</name>

<build>     
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateEbpacObjectMapJar</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions> 
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <memoryInitialSize>50m</memoryInitialSize>
                <memoryMaximumSize>80m</memoryMaximumSize>                  
                <schemaDirectory>src/xsddir</schemaDirectory>
                <xmlConfigs>
                    <xmlConfig implementation="java.io.File">src/myconfig.xsdconfig</xmlConfig>
                </xmlConfigs>
                <sourceGenerationDirectory>target/generated/JARSources</sourceGenerationDirectory>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>    
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-xpath</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-xmlpublic</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-qname</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

xsd config below:

```
xb:config 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xb="http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config" 
    xmlns:ebpac="http://bct.com/platform/factory"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config xmlconfig.xsd">
<xb:usertype name="cl:myClass" javaname="java.lang.Class">
    <xb:staticHandler>com.ImplClassHandler</xb:staticHandler>
</xb:usertype>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look into `<scope>provided</scope>` tag usage in Maven depedency, the jars would be available at the compile time from your .m2 directories; but not included in packaging.
However, you need to make sure that the library jar should be available somewhere in the classpath of the JVM.

Comment: how to make sure lib jars in the  classpath of the JVM and explained my problem bit clear

Comment: Please post the pom.xml